# Linux "/dev/SDA" goes read only file system on SDB device failure

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, boot, udev

i have a very peculiar issue that is running in my system.

Using debian linux :

My system boots up very normally with a primary and secondary hard disk.
suddenly my secondary hard disk fails with some I/O Error DRDY UNC errors which tends make my primary SDA to read only filesystem.

1. how to avoid primary to be changed as read only
2. What are all the steps i need to do for removing the SDB reference from the system
3. Is it possible to detect SDB removal from the system

   - i was not able notice anything on SDA becoming readonly file ssytem

Kernel Log::

```
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.251575] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.251641] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.251699] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.251768] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.251771]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.251932] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.251990] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.373641] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.405721] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  203.406808] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.661201] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.661267] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.661324] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.661393] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.661396]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.661556] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.661614] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.769671] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.817705] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.817776] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.817836] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.817930] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.818105] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.818193]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.818722]         25 00 17 f8 
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.818914] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.819056] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 25 00 17 f8 00 00 08 00
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.819477] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 620763128
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.819542] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 70778879
15:52:13::kernel::[  205.819625] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.257956] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.258023] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.258081] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.258149] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.258153]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.258314] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.258372] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.377642] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.409704] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  208.409771] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.667618] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.667684] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.667742] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.667810] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.667814]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.667974] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.668048] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.789641] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.821716] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  210.821783] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.088237] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.088302] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.088359] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.088427] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.088430]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.088590] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.088648] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.209641] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.241715] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  213.241782] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.508902] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.508969] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.509028] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.509098] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.509101]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.509263] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.509321] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.629629] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.661719] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  215.661787] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  217.918569] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  217.918636] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  217.918694] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  217.918762] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  217.918765]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  217.918927] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  217.918986] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  218.041627] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  218.073729] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  218.073795] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.328276] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.328342] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.328400] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.328469] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.328472]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.328633] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.328690] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.449628] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.481707] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.481776] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.481835] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.481928] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.482104] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.482193]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.482720]         25 00 17 f8 
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.482911] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.483053] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 25 00 17 f8 00 00 08 00
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.483473] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 620763128
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.483538] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 70778879
15:52:13::kernel::[  220.483621] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.770949] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.771016] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.771075] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.771144] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.771147]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.771309] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.771367] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.881632] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.913731] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.913798] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.941704] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
15:52:13::kernel::[  222.941731] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.202590] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.202677] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.202737] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.202806] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.202809]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.202969] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.203027] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.325628] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.357730] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  225.357801] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.645290] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.645356] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.645414] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.645483] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.645486]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.645648] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.645706] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.765627] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.797703] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  227.797773] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.098939] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.099010] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.099069] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.099138] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.099141]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.099303] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.099361] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.221629] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.253724] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  230.253795] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.552618] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.552690] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.552750] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.552819] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.552823]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.552984] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.553045] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.672647] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.705717] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  232.705787] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  234.995333] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
15:52:13::kernel::[  234.995405] ata1.01: BMDMA stat 0x65
15:52:13::kernel::[  234.995465] ata1.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
15:52:13::kernel::[  234.995534] ata1.01: cmd 25/00:08:f8:17:00/00:00:25:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
15:52:13::kernel::[  234.995537]          res 51/40:00:f8:17:00/40:00:25:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)
15:52:13::kernel::[  234.996798] ata1.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
15:52:13::kernel::[  234.996857] ata1.01: error: { UNC }
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.117634] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.149719] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.149793] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.149852] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.149946] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.150121] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.150209]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.150734]         25 00 17 f8 
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.150925] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.151067] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 25 00 17 f8 00 00 08 00
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.151486] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 620763128
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.151551] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 70778879
15:52:13::kernel::[  235.151637] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.328133] udev[324]: starting version 164
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.847381] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input1
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.869301] ACPI: SSDT 1f7ae190 0023C (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Ist 00003000 INTL 20051117)
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.870585] ACPI: SSDT 1f7ae460 00594 (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Cst 00003001 INTL 20051117)
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.909933] Monitor-Mwait will be used to enter C-1 state
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.910903] Monitor-Mwait will be used to enter C-2 state
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.911011] Monitor-Mwait will be used to enter C-3 state
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.911033] Marking TSC unstable due to TSC halts in idle
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.911382] processor LNXCPU:00: registered as cooling_device0
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.912582] ACPI: SSDT 1f7ae0c0 000CC (v01  PmRef  Cpu1Ist 00003000 INTL 20051117)
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.913512] ACPI: SSDT 1f7ae3d0 00085 (v01  PmRef  Cpu1Cst 00003000 INTL 20051117)
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.934806] Switching to clocksource hpet
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.951454] processor LNXCPU:01: registered as cooling_device1
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.963534] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.963651] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.963941] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.964096] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.965371] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.965496] USB Serial support registered for generic
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.965921] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
15:52:13::kernel::[  236.965996] usbserial: USB Serial Driver core
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.241394] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.241512] ACPI: Video Device [IGD] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.261956] USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.262819] ftdi_sio 2-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.263068] usb 2-2: Detected FT232BM
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.263131] usb 2-2: Number of endpoints 2
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.263194] usb 2-2: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.263256] usb 2-2: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.263318] usb 2-2: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.264372] intel_rng: FWH not detected
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.264747] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.264864] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.264932] ftdi_sio: v1.5.0:USB FTDI Serial Converters Driver
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.274123] parport_pc 00:0d: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.274251] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.591236] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
15:52:13::kernel::[  237.800484] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.122025] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.137758] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.137823] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.272620] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.287023] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (1871:0d01)
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.294155] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.309758] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.309823] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.395897] i915 0000:00:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.395973] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.405049] [drm] set up 7M of stolen space
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.406952] input: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input5
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.407199] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.407274] USB Video Class driver (v0.1.0)
15:52:13::kernel::[  238.750953] [drm] initialized overlay support
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456610] [drm:edid_is_valid] *ERROR* Raw EDID:
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456679] <3>ff 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  .???????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456686] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456692] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456698] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456704] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456709] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456715] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456721] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  240.456726] 
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094550] [drm:edid_is_valid] *ERROR* Raw EDID:
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094619] <3>ff 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  .???????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094626] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094632] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094637] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094643] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094649] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094655] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094661] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  242.094665] 
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733641] [drm:edid_is_valid] *ERROR* Raw EDID:
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733710] <3>ff 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  .???????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733717] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733723] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733729] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733735] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733741] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733747] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733753] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  243.733757] 
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373529] [drm:edid_is_valid] *ERROR* Raw EDID:
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373598] <3>ff 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  .???????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373605] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373611] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373617] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373623] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373629] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373635] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373641] <3>3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f 3f  ????????????????
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373645] 
15:52:13::kernel::[  245.373698] i915 0000:00:02.0: VGA-1: EDID invalid.
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.065548] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.072122] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.072126] registered panic notifier
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.072326] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.072563] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.072799] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.861037] hda_codec: ALC888: BIOS auto-probing.
15:52:13::kernel::[  246.862623] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/input/input6
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.216847] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.288131] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.288242] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.326018] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.341769] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.343158] ata1: EH complete
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.646542] Adding 2095096k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2095096k 
15:52:13::kernel::[  247.801381] EXT3 FS on sda1, internal journal
15:52:13::kernel::[  248.014353] loop: module loaded
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.435364] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.438402] EXT3 FS on sda5, internal journal
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.441482] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.516710] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.519947] EXT3 FS on sda2, internal journal
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.523090] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.969583] r8169: eth0: link up
15:52:13::kernel::[  249.972585] r8169: eth0: link up
15:52:13::kernel::[  250.830980] fuse init (API version 7.13)
15:52:22::kernel::[  260.936015] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
15:52:22::kernel::[  261.320413] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A disabled
15:52:22::kernel::[  261.338235] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
15:52:22::kernel::[  261.338298] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
15:52:22::kernel::[  261.408174] hda_codec: ALC888: BIOS auto-probing.
15:52:22::kernel::[  261.409625] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/input/input7
15:52:23::kernel::[  261.862230] udev[1471]: starting version 164
15:52:23::kernel::[  262.158543] intel_rng: FWH not detected
15:52:24::kernel::[  263.314541] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:24::kernel::[  263.329765] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:24::kernel::[  263.329777] ata1: EH complete
15:52:24::kernel::[  263.353665] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:24::kernel::[  263.369782] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/133
15:52:24::kernel::[  263.369794] ata1: EH complete
15:53:23::kernel::[  321.725059] usb 3-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
15:53:23::kernel::[  321.965094] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04b3, idProduct=3025
15:53:23::kernel::[  321.965103] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
15:53:23::kernel::[  321.965111] usb 3-1: Product: USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard.
15:53:23::kernel::[  321.965116] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: LITE-ON Technology
15:53:23::kernel::[  321.965421] usb 3-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
15:53:23::kernel::[  321.999751] input: LITE-ON Technology USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard. as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input8
15:53:23::kernel::[  322.000373] generic-usb 0003:04B3:3025.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [LITE-ON Technology USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard.] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0
16:05:12::kernel::imklog 4.6.4, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

Comment: Why are you removing hard disk and/or the power to your disks on your system?

Comment: @ewwhite :: I just do that for testing but actual scenario is that SDB are getting DRDY errors which i was not able to simulate.But with logs i see that when SDB gets a DRDY error it makes my SDA inaccessible and makes it read only file system

Comment: @ewwhite : Modified post with actual scenario

Comment: OK, we see the errors on `sdb`, but no evidence of `sda` going write-only.  Can you add any logs about that?

Comment: @MadHatter :; Added more kernel info

Comment: I see more errors on `sdb`, and a lot of irrelevant junk, but still nothing about `sda` going read-only.

Comment: @MadHatter :: i verified the complete kernel log and not able to see any reference for SDA going read only but i see below scenarions

Comment: How do you know it's gone read-only, then, and how do you know that it's correlated with the `sdb` errors?

Comment: @MadHatter :: i verified the complete kernel log and not able to see any reference for SDA going read only but i see below scenarios. 1. Screen is flooded with I/O errors. 2. System goes to frozen state.

Comment: I ask again: **what has either of those to do with proving that `sda` goes read-only?**  At the moment, it looks like `sdb` fails, and that freezes the system.  Get any data that's on it off, and replace it.

Comment: @MadHatter : Yes.My syslog update did not happen and also i ran a touch test in console window which said Command not found.

Comment: @MadHatter : Also to add up .I will anyway replace the secondary drive but those are remote sites and hence could take days for field engineers to reach.in mean time i dont want the system to be in down state.so how do i make primary gracefully handle secondary failures.

Comment: **I have not yet seen any evidence that the primary is having any problems at all.**  The two things you note above (syslog, command not found) aren't evidence without knowing which file systems are on which drive.  Grant has a pretty good point below, anyway: once a device goes crazy on a bus, it can often hang the bus.  We know from your kernel logs that the kernel is continually reinitializing the controller to try to shock `sdb` back to life, and while it's doing that, `sda` will be inaccessible as well.

Comment: @MadHatter :: is there no other ways to stop SDB detection on its failures??

Comment: You **might** get lucky simply unmounting all the partitions that are on `sdb`, so that the kernel has no need ever to write to or read from the drive.  That **might** stop the kernel tickling the failing hardware.

Comment: @MadHatter : what is the best way to monitor the occurence of this issue..how should i monitor kernel for this errors..is DMESG d only way or what is the suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11612/discussion-between-madhatter-and-ragav) , if you can make it in the next ten minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

sdb is failing, as evidenced by the line:

> [sdb] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed

You need make sure everything is backed up and replace the drive.
For good measure, check all other drives in the system to see if they are having issues, using the drive manufacturer's tools.

From what you've posted I can't tell what's going on with sda.  But its quite common for the entire system to freeze when a drive starts failing.  Or for the IDE or SATA controller both drives are attached to to hang.  Either of those could cause it to detect a file system error, and switch to read only mode to try to prevent any damage.

Comment: Yes so true and that this freeze looks to be the issue which you are pointing in.But is there a way where i can point kernel to avoid re-initializing the controller on SDB failures so that i can make sure that my system is up and running.

Comment: Physically remove the hard drive.  Unmounting all partitions on the drive *might* stop it, but no guarantees.

Comment: :: since the machine is in remote places i really want to stop down time.if there is linux hack for detecting failed SDB devices i would prefer that.

Comment: @ragav are you trying to still be able to use the failing drive?  Linux isn't "detecting" that it's failing - it is just failing.  The drive doesn't respond and locks up the system.  Stopping all use of the failing drive might stop it from locking up.

Comment: no we have to replace the drive but since it is remote we dont want system to be in down state.so for tht time we want the primary to gracefully handle secondary so that system will be up and running.

Comment: @Ragav Is the drive unmounted?  If its unmounted and the system isn't accessing it anymore, but its still locking up, there isn't much you can do but have the datacenter pull the drive out.

Comment: Yes we did not even mount the drive and error occurred.and is there some UDEV property available where i can tweak to fix this.(may be the storage rules??)      http://serverfault.com/questions/112147/tell-ubuntu-to-ignore-dead-hard-drive-during-booting